# Loading context in talend with tContextLoad when variable contains the separator

Tags: talend

I am trying to load variables through a tContextLoad (with tFileInputDelimited as the input).
My separator is equal ("=").
Problem is, one of my variable contains this sign :

```
variable_01=http://someUrl/source=someSource
```

I tried to escape "=" character with backslash, double-backslash, but still when the variable is loaded, I have

```
variable_01=http://someUrl/source
```

How could I escape this character ? Important notice : when using implicit contextLoad from project settings, I don't have this issue. (unfortunately I can't use contextLoad implicit in this case)

Comment: I don't have this problem with the 7.0 version of talend. Talend just use the first "=" as separator of key/value. The second doesn't disapear in my job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use the component `tFileInputProperties` instead of `tFileInputDelimited`.
With this component only the first "=" of a line is used as a separator.

Comment: Thank you it worked ! I didn't know this component.